# Setting a button's clicked state in TCL

Tags: button, tcl, tk-toolkit

In TCL, how can I programmatically set the 'clicked' state of a button? So for example, I have two latched buttons. When I latch button one to 'on', I want button two to also latch 'on'. In something like VB its just button1.value.

Comment: There are several kinds of buttons: which kind are you referring to?

Comment: `[.button2 state]` is a rough equivalent to VB's `button2.value`

Comment: Normal buttons. Not radios or check boxes. Plain old boring buttons. According to the doc (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/button.htm#M10) state is for whether the button is enabled etc:  "Specifies one of three states for the button: normal, active, or disabled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a standard button like that; it's designed to be only down when actively pressed. For a button that you toggle on and off, use a checkbutton where you've turned the indicator off (which makes it change L&F).

```
checkbutton .button1 -variable latch -indicator false -text "Button 1"
checkbutton .button2 -variable latch -indicator false -text "Button 2"
pack .button1 .button2
```

Note that on some platforms, this might not work. (It doesn't on OSX…) However, it is how you slave boolean choices together.